# Why does Sentry log errors caught in except block?

Tags: python, sentry

I use Sentry for inspecting the errors. In one part of my code, there's a `try/except` block for a snippet that uses `langdetect` and throws a `LangDetectException`. That code looks like

```
try:
    return detect(text)
except LangDetectException as error:
    logging.error(repr(error))
```

Well I don't really understand the docs from Sentry about whether they should log errors in `except` scope or log only unhandled errors? In one place, they say that Sentry shouldn't log caught errors on other it says it should so I'm a little bit confused. The mentioned code, when text was made only from non-alpha chars, threw the `LangDetectException('No features in text.')` error but also listed it on Sentry as an error. Why does this happen? Obviously, this is a caught error and I want to have it only logged in my logs and not in Sentry. Is this a normal behavior for Sentry or there's something I'm missing?

Comment: I don't use python, but maybe you're logging the error in the console and Sentry is detecting that. Maybe there is an option is disable checking for error messages in the console.

Comment: Yeah, the error is being logged into the console. On top of that, I found out that this shouldn't be logged as error but rather as a warning so `logging.warning` should be used. Haven't used Sentry before so didn't know that this would happen, I thought that only uncaught exceptions get logged on Sentry. Anyway, thanks for the answer :))

Answer (score 1):

Creating an official answer. I just ran into this also. @zoran404's comment is correct.

The Python Sentry package will create an issue for logging.error() calls by default.

> Calling sentry_sdk.init() already integrates with the logging module. It is equivalent to this explicit configuration:

```
import logging
import sentry_sdk
from sentry_sdk.integrations.logging import LoggingIntegration

# All of this is already happening by default!
sentry_logging = LoggingIntegration(
    level=logging.INFO,        # Capture info and above as breadcrumbs
    event_level=logging.ERROR  # Send errors as events
)
```

from https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/guides/logging/

Comment: Ok, but how do I configure Sentry to log ONLY  unhandled exceptions?